# Writing IF, AND, OR together

Tags: excel

I'm new to excel. Trying to create formulas for Lab values obtained in a clinical trial.

For Example: SCr value for Male subjects must be >=1.5 but <=3.5. So I enter my lab values in Visit1 sheet, and then have  queries populate in another sheet to discuss with Physicians.

I wrote a formula as follows based on previous posts on this site:

```
=IF(AND(Visit1!F26>=1.5, Visit1!F26<=3.5, Visit1!D6=Codes!G3), "", "SCr value out of range"
```

The formula works but I would like to have the message "Please confirm why the SCr value was not obtained" if I enter "Not Obtained" in Visit1!F26 instead of "SCr value out of Range"

p.s. I have things like gender, and "Not obtained" in my Codes! sheet as drop downs.

Please let me know if you need further clarification on my question, thanks,

Comment: Can you do it like this: `=IF(Visit1!F26="Not Obtained","Please confirm why the SCr value was not obtained",IF(AND(Visit1!F26>=1.5, Visit1!F26<=3.5, Visit1!D6=Codes!G3), "", "SCr value out of range"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, when you work with nested `ifs` and longer formulas, it is probably a best practice to put spaces between the different segements.

Like the formula in your case:
`=IF(Visit1!F26="Not Obtained","Please confirm why the SCr value was not obtained",IF(AND(Visit1!F26>=1.5, Visit1!F26<=3.5, Visit1!D6=Codes!G3), "", "SCr value out of range"))`

Can become:

[image]

Press `Alt+Enter` to get the new line.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the advice, that format definitely helps follow the flow of the formula much better.

Comment: Welcome, @Merj8 :)